# How Do I Install MediaWiki Parsoid on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, mediawiki, parsoid

I am attempting to get VisualEditor for MediaWiki set up and configured on Windows. (Server 2012 R2 Core) I am following the steps here : https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid/Developer_Setup

The page states :

> As of April 2015, the html5 package has only an optional dependency on
>   jsdom, and so installing contextify should no longer be necessary.

However when I try to compile parsoid with npm errors there are errors about contextify. So he dependency must still exist... The error returned is :

```
C:\Installs\Parsoid\parsoid>npm install
> contextify@0.1.15 install C:\Installs\Parsoid\parsoid\node_modules\contextify
> node-gyp rebuild
C:\Installs\Parsoid\parsoid\node_modules\contextify>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nod
ejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not fi
nd WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid versio
n number. [C:\Installs\Parsoid\parsoid\node_modules\contextify\build\contextify.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(356,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exit
ed with code -1073741515. [C:\Installs\Parsoid\parsoid\node_modules\contextify\build\contextify.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\buil
d.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_m
odules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Installs\Parsoid\parsoid\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v5.4.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:contextify@0.1.15 contextify@0.1.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:contextify@0.1.15 Exit status 1
```

I have installed the VC 2015 Build tools, python 2.7 - and set up node to use these. I dont really know where to go next, any suggestions?

Comment: Doing a bit more digging - it might be that I need VC 2013 instead of 2015. Can anyone tell me how / why node is complaining it cant compile a file which doesnt exist? The contextify folder doesnt exist - C:\Installs\Parsoid\parsoid\node_modules\contextify\build\contextify.vcxproj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the above errors are not errors at all - but warning. Parsoid had downloaded its other dependencies and running it afterward worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

See my post [How to install VisualEditor for MediaWiki on Windows](https://samirmmbr.wordpress.com/2019/05/20/como-instalar-visualeditor-para-mediawiki-no-windows/)
 and important step 10 update  uri: ‘http://localhost/w/api.php’ to uri: http://localhost:81/mediawiki/api.php